# What's the best method to recreate Android Jelly Bean Lockscreen mechanism on iOS

Tags: ios7

I know the question sounds a bit vague, so here comes the pics.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

I'm trying to recreate this same mechanism inside of an iOS app (not actually making a lockscreen). The problem is I'm at a loss, and am not sure if I should go the openGL route, or if there is a native iOS.

I realize this could be subjective, however I'm simply asking for A method, ANY method lol, all I need is a *pointer, and I'll research the rest.

Comment: Questions should be answerable not just discussable...

Comment: This is called a "radial menu". Some search about it will yield much more results.

Comment: @wumm you'll notice in my question `I'm simply asking for A method, ANY method lol, all I need is a *pointer, and I'll research the rest.`